# Explicit specialization of variable template

Tags: c++, templates, extern

How can I manage explicit specialization of a variable template?

I have in a header:

```
// foo.h
#pragma once
template<typename T> extern T minBound;
```

And in a single nearby compilation unit:

```
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
template<> int minBound<int> = 0x80000000;
template<> short minBound<short> = 0x8000;
```

And a main:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << minBound<int> << std::endl; // Hopefully -2147483648
    std::cout << minBound<short> << std::endl; // Hopefully -32768
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `g++ *.cpp`.

The linker tells me that I have `multiple definition of minBound<int>` and `multiple definition of minBound<short>`. Can variable templates not be extern? What I have in mind is different values for various template specializations; how might I go about accomplishing this?

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1, gcc version 7.4.0. Tested it on WSL using GCC 7.4 and 8.3; no issue.

<sub>I can just make it a zero-argument function, I know, but that's boring.</sub>

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. Can you provide a minimal `foo.h`, `foo.cpp`, and `main.cpp` together with the command line you're using to try to build the program?

Comment: @Brian Updated.

Comment: Can't reproduce with gcc 7.4.0. What version do you have?

Comment: There may be a hint in the output of `g++ -c main.cpp; nm -C main.o`.

Comment: Have mercy for future maintainer and just enclose this variables in a class (as static fields).

Comment: Are you trying to replicate [std::numeric_limits::min()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min) functionality?

Comment: @MarekR Pretty much. Haskell Prelude's `Bounded` typeclass. And for whatever reason, it's working just fine today...

Answer (score 1):

Any explicit specialization is like a normal function in that it must be declared everywhere it’s used (*i.e.*, in a header) *and* defined in one source file.  For a variable template, the non-defining declaration contains `extern`, just like for any other variable.  However, GCC doesn’t seem to support this (per Wandbox).